# Scope validation with FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: symfony, fosoauthserverbundle, oauth-2.0

I'm using FOSOAuthServerBundle with Symfony 2.7.

I would like to use scopes to differenciate two types of clients :

- `scope_default` : the client can only access the authenticated user information
- `scope_master` : the client can read everything

I added the property `reachable_scopes` in my `Client` Entity.

How can I make sure a client won't ask for the `scope_master` if he isn't allowed to ?

Thank you !